# Parse a string with multiple XML-like tags using Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I have a string which looks like the following:

```
   string = " <SET-TOPIC>INITIATE</SET-TOPIC>

    <SETPROFILE>
      <PROFILE-KEY>predicates_live</PROFILE-KEY>
      <PROFILE-VALUE>yes</PROFILE-VALUE>
    </SETPROFILE>

    <think>
      <set><name>first_time_initiate</name>yes</set>
    </think>

    <SETPROFILE>
      <PROFILE-KEY>first_time_initiate</PROFILE-KEY>
      <PROFILE-VALUE>YES</PROFILE-VALUE>
    </SETPROFILE>"
```

My objective is to be able to read out each top level that is in caps with the parse.  I use a `case` statement to evaluate what is the top level key, such as `<SETPROFILE>` but there can be lots of different values, and then run a method that does different things with the contnts of the tag.

What this means is I need to be able to know very easily:

- `top_level_keys = ['SET-TOPIC', 'SET-PROFILE', 'SET-PROFILE']`
- when I pass in the key know the full value
- `parsed[0].value = {:PROFILE-KEY => predicates_live, :PROFILE-VALUE => yes}`
- `parsed[0].key = ['SET-TOPIC']`

I currently parse the whole string as follows:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(string)
parsed = doc.search('*').each_with_object({}){ |n, h|
  h[n.name] = n.text
}
```

As a result, I only parse and know of the second  tag.  The values from the first tag do not show up in the `parsed` variable.

I have control over what the tags are, if that helps.

But I need to be able to parse and know the contents of both  tag as a result of the parse because I need to apply a method for each instance of the node.

**Note**: the string also contains just regular text, both before, in between, and after the XML-like tags.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are going to achieve. The problem is that you are overriding hash keys by new values. The easiest way to collect values is to store them in array:

```
parsed = doc.search('*').each_with_object({}) do |n, h| 
  # h[n.name] = n.text :: removed because it overrides values
  (h[n.name] ||= []) << n.text 
end
```

Comment: Thanks. If we remove the override and create an array that would be fine. Is there a downside or trade off doing it this way ?

Comment: My goal is to be able to have a method which can parse through each distinct tag and apply the method.  Different nodes then take the parsed values, apply the appropriate method, then strip out the tag from the string or replace it based on the method.

Comment: I get an error: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` are we turning a hash into an array?

Comment: I think I figured it out -- but the large point goes back to your original question, what I want to achieve.  Let me update the desription.